# How to exposeTransactionAware on a 2nd sessionFactory in hibernate4 + spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, cucumber, hibernate-4.x

The test below was working in my application with Hibernate3. When I upgraded it to hibernate4, it started failing.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations=false,locations={
"/hibernate/spring-SF-tests.xml",
"/hibernate/spring-transaction.xml",
"/hibernate/testBeans.xml"
,"/hibernate/spring-audit.xml",
"/hibernate/iwrs-mail-beans-test.xml",
"/hibernate/fake-audit-meaning.xml"
})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager", defaultRollback=true)
public class CodeAuditIntegrationTest extends CodeIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory auditFactory;


@Before
public void cleanAudit(){
auditFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from AuditLogRecord").executeUpdate();
}

@Test
public void clinicalTrialAssociationTest() {
super.clinicalTrialAssociationTest();
}

}
```

Which is failing with:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)

I have 2 different session factories in my app: sessionFactory and auditFactory. Both are configured in spring (see [1]).

The problem is that in an hibernate4 configuration **the property exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory was removed**. I had that set to true for my auditFactory. I believe removing this property makes the injected auditFactory not being able to pick up the session in the transaction (as txManger is configured for sessionFactory), therefore yielding the error.

Questions:

1. **how can I make the auditFactory have transactions managed by spring on this test?**
2. **Is that what was happening with the exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory property in hibernate 3?**

The only alternative I see is to wrap all the code that uses auditFactory in a Helper class annotated with @Transactional(otherTxManager). I did try that, but I got a couple of additional problems there:

1. I needed to use a separate DataSource (else I'd get [2])
2. Using 2 separate datasources I'll get a similar error on my Cucumber tests, now related with the transactionManager [3]

[1] The relavant XML configuration:

```
<bean id="txManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

        <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2dll}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${hibernate.sql_scripts}</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan">...</property>
<property name="annotatedPackages">...</property>
<property name="mappingLocations">...</property>

<property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />
<property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
</bean>

<bean id="auditFactory" scope="singleton"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory"> -->needs to be removed in hibernate4!
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property name="mappingLocations">...</property>
<property name="packagesToScan">...</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2dll}</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />
</bean>
```

[2] Problem with using the same dataSource for the two factories:

> org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:329)

[3] Problem in cucumber tests due to declaring 2 transaction managers:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single bean but found 2: txAudit,txManager